# I commited when I was on an old commit, how can I find that commit?

Tags: git, github

I was working on some changes and I commited on an old commit, I executed `history` on bash and I found out this.

```
1000  git checkout 7227... <-- I was on branch main and then I checkout on commit 7227...
  --- Working on changes ---
1012  git commit -am "Login corrections" <-- I did not realize I was not working on main branch
1013  git pull origin main <-- I found out the problem and then I checkout to main
```

I moved to branch `main` and now I don't know where to find the commit I did with message `Login corrections` as shown before. I tried `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` if I could find anything related but I did not find anything.

Comment: `git log --all` should show the commit. But in such a case, `git reflog` is usually a helpful first step. Does it show you the amended commit?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do [`git checkout $commithash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), you end up in [*detached head*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head) state. This means that you are *not* on a branch – any commit operations you do will create commits not reachable from any branch.

[`git log --all`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) only shows commits reachable from any ref (branch or tag). This excludes "detached head" commits.

But all is not lost. Git provides the [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) comand to show how a certain ref evolved over time. Without arguments, it will show the last states of the `HEAD` ref (your currently checked out commit).

You should be able to see your detached commit there. First find your checkout out commit, and then a line above should be a line containing "commit (amend): Login corrections", starting with the commit hash of this commit. You might as well use grep to quickly limit the output: `git reflog | grep -3 'Login corrections'`.

Once you have that, you can create branch from that commit: [`git branch recover-detached $commithash_from_reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch). Then, checkout this branch, inspect its history, cherry-pick, rebase, or merge it.